# How to define initializers in a protocol extension?

Tags: swift, initialization, swift2, protocols, swift-extensions

```
protocol Car {
     var wheels : Int { get set}

     init(wheels: Int)

}

extension Car {
    init(wheels: Int) {
        self.wheels = wheels
    }
}
```

on self.wheels = wheels i get the error

```
Error: variable 'self' passed by reference before being initialized
```

How can I define the initializer in the protocol extension?

Comment: If you're using simple structures you can omit the initializer in the protocol, since it will be synthesized by the compiler!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As you can see this doesn't work under these circumstances because when compiling, one has to make sure that all properties are initialized before using the struct/enum/class.

You can make another initializer a requirement so the compiler knows that all properties are initialized:

```
protocol Car {
    var wheels : Int { get set }
    // make another initializer
    // (which you probably don't want to provide a default implementation)
    // a protocol requirement. Care about recursive initializer calls :)
    init()
    init(wheels: Int)

}

extension Car {
    // now you can provide a default implementation
    init(wheels: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.wheels = wheels
    }
}

// example usage

// mark as final
final class HoverCar: Car {
    var wheels = 0
    init() {}
}

let drivableHoverCar = HoverCar(wheels: 4)
drivableHoverCar.wheels // 4
```

As of Xcode 7.3 beta 1 it works with `structs` as expected but not with classes since if they are not `final` the `init(wheels: Int)` in the protocol is a `required init` and it can be overridden therefore it cannot be added through an extension. Workaround (as the complier suggests): Make the `class` `final`.

### Another workaround (in depth; without `final class`)

To work with classes without making them final you can also drop the `init(wheels: Int)` requirement in the protocol. It seems that it behaves no different than before but consider this code:

```
protocol Car {
    var wheels : Int { get set }
    init()
    // there is no   init(wheels: Int)
}

extension Car {
    init(wheels: Int) {
        self.init()
        print("Extension")
        self.wheels = wheels
    }
}

class HoverCar: Car {
    var wheels = 0
    required init() {}
    init(wheels: Int) {
        print("HoverCar")
        self.wheels = wheels
    }
}

// prints "HoverCar"
let drivableHoverCar = HoverCar(wheels: 4)

func makeNewCarFromCar<T: Car>(car: T) -> T {
    return T(wheels: car.wheels)
}

// prints "Extension"
makeNewCarFromCar(drivableHoverCar)
```

So if you make a `Car` from a generic context where the type on which you call `init` is only to be known as `Car` the extension initializer is called even though an initializer is defined in `HoverCar`. This only occurs because there is no `init(wheels: Int)` requirement in the protocol.

If you add it you have the former problem with declaring the `class` as `final` but now it prints two times "HoverCar". Either way the second problem probably never occurs so it might be a better solution.

Sidenote: If I have made some mistakes (code, language, grammar,...) you're welcome to correct me :)

Comment: Can you add the declaration of the class to further illustrate your solution?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt Which class do you mean? `Car` is a protocol and its declaration is complete.

Comment: I mean a class that would implement the Car protocol.

Comment: @CraigGrummitt Thank you for commenting on this answer. While adding an example I found a second solution which is probably better than the first one :) See edited answer above

Comment: thanks for showing the class. The main problem I see with this solution is that you either need to declare a default value for wheels(in the var declaration or the required init()) or you need to declare it an implicitly unwrapped Optional. It's as good a solution as we have for the problem, I just wonder whether that in itself smells like perhaps we just shouldn't be implementing initializers in protocol extensions! :)

Comment: @CraigGrummitt I totally agree with you. The requirement of a default init which forces you to set a default value for wheels is kind of bad. However there is a discussion going on for Swift 3 about partial initializers which could solve this problem.

Comment: @Qbyte `drivableHoverCar.wheels` prints 4, not 6.

Comment: "but now it prints two times 'HoverCar'" mentioned for the 2nd approach.
Why would that happen???

Comment: @pravir This behavior is due to static and dynamic dispatch, see 'Examples' in https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/static-vs-dynamic-dispatch-in-swift-a-decisive-choice-cece1e872d. If we specify 'init(wheels:Int)' in the protocol, then it uses dynamic dispatch. If the method is only defined in the `extension`, then it uses static dispatch.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this is a **horribly wrong answer**. That is: things are just working for you because the concrete class in your **example** is a class that can be initialized with `init()`. 9 out of 10, you have a class that can't be initialized that simply...

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that this isn't possible, because the protocol extension can't know which properties the conforming class or struct has - and therefore cannot guarantee they are correctly initialized.

If there are ways to get around this, I'm very interested to know! :)

Answer (score 6):

@Qbyte is correct.

In addition, you can take a look at my [Configurable](https://github.com/onmyway133/Configurable)

In that I have `Initable` protocol

```
public protocol Initable {
    // To make init in protocol extension work
    init()
}

public extension Initable {
    public init(@noescape block: Self -> Void) {
        self.init()
        block(self)
    }
}
```

Then in order to conform to it

```
extension Robot: Initable { }
```

I have 2 ways, using `final` or implement `init`

```
final class Robot {
    var name: String?
    var cute = false
}

class Robot {
    var name: String?
    var cute = false

    required init() {

    }
}
```

Comment: nice. Finally a "my" link that has essential parts shown

Answer (score 2):

May not be the same but in my case instead of using init I used a static func to return the object of the class.

```
protocol Serializable {
   static func object(fromJSON json:JSON) -> AnyObject?
}

class User {
    let name:String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension User:Serializable {

    static func object(fromJSON json:JSON) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let name = json["name"] else {
            return nil
        }

        return User(name:name)
     }

}
```

Then to create the object I do something like:

```
let user = User.object(fromJSON:json) as? User
```

I know its not the best thing ever but its the best solution I could find to not couple business model with the data layer.

NOTE: I'm lazy and I coded everything directly in the comment so if something doesn't work let me know.