# Public default init in protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have this code:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    init()
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    public init() {
        self.init()
    }
}

public final class MyClass: MyProtocol {}
```

I got an error saying:

> Initializer 'init()' must be declared public because it matches a
>   requirement in public protocol 'MyProtocol'

If I remove the access control (`public`) before `final`, it works. But why? Is there any way I can let the protocol handle the init? I thought all members of protocols are implicitly `public` by default.

More strange is that a different `init` that can only be found in the `extension` is `public` by default:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    init()
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    public init() {
        self.init()
    }

    public init(youDoNotHaveToImplementMe: Any) {
        self.init()
    }
}

public final class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    public init() {}
}
```

As you can see, the new init is actually `public`. I expected my normal `init` should be `public` as well. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass` is supposed to conform to given protocol `MyProtocol`, even if `MyClass` is public. But how would `MyClass` conform to `MyProtocol`, if `MyClass` were public but its init not visible from the other module? It would conform to `MyProtocol`(signature says so) and at the same time not(no visible init).

> Since your protocol can't be certain to cover all members of the class that uses it, any initializer you declare in your protocol will need to delegate initialization of the "unknown" members of the class to another initializer provided by the class itself.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801399/protocol-extension-initializer)

Since `MyClass`‘ default initializer is internal the protocol does not conform to the protocol if no public init is declared in-class while `MyClass` is public.